# Jenkins job not responding

Tags: jenkins

One of my jenkins job does not respond at all, it does not open even. I am not able to figure out the cause for this. However, I gathered thread dump for this particular job, Can somebody help me with this or let me know something on this?

PS: I have restarted Jenkins many times. I cannot delete the job.

Thread Dump:

```
Handling GET /job/TradexCC/ : qtp906199566-1158" Id=1158 Group=main RUNNABLE
    at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.iterator(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:925)
    at hudson.model.Actionable.getAction(Actionable.java:104)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.AbstractProjectAction.getResultAction(AbstractProjectAction.java:388)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.AbstractProjectAction.getLastFinishedBuild(AbstractProjectAction.java:403)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.AbstractProjectAction.getLastAction(AbstractProjectAction.java:370)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.AbstractProjectAction.getIconFileName(AbstractProjectAction.java:341)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor251.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.PropertyExecutor.execute(PropertyExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelGetterImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:314)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTArrayAccess.evaluateExpr(ASTArrayAccess.java:185)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTIdentifier.execute(ASTIdentifier.java:75)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:83)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.value(ASTReference.java:57)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTNENode.value(ASTNENode.java:55)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTExpression.value(ASTExpression.java:54)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTExpressionExpression.value(ASTExpressionExpression.java:56)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.ExpressionImpl.evaluate(ExpressionImpl.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression.evaluate(ExpressionFactory2.java:89)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.expression.ExpressionSupport.evaluateRecurse(ExpressionSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.expression.ExpressionSupport.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionSupport.java:71)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:97)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:186)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ForEachTag.doTag(ForEachTag.java:150)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:270)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:111)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:55)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:138)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:270)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:90)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:270)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:111)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:90)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:270)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:111)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:55)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:138)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:270)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:90)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:270)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:111)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:55)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:55)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:45)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyClassTearOff.serveIndexJelly(JellyClassTearOff.java:64)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet.handleIndexRequest(JellyFacet.java:106)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:554)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:650)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:225)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:45)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:565)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:650)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:481)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:152)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1336)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:86)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:162)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:134)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:89)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:162)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:134)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:89)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:81)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:73)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Are you running your Jenkins server on Linux or Windows? You want to delete the job configuration or do you just want to kill your build?

Comment: I am running jenkins on Windows. No I dont want to delete the job, the thing is job is not opening i.e. when I click on the job name the page does not takes me to job configuration or status or workspace tab page, it just keeps waiting for the next page. There's no action simply.

Comment: Did you install a new plugin recently? Or did you change something in the global settings?

Comment: No new plugin installed & no changes done in global settings.

Comment: On the Jenkins machine, if you backup the jobs data (the whole job folder including the config.xml file + all the relevant folders), can you try to: stop the Jenkins server, remove the job folder, recreate the job folder with the same name, copy the config.xml from the backup, restart the Jenkins server. If it's OK, you can try to copy the other folders and reload the configuration from the disk (from the "manage Jenkins" menu).

Comment: This too did not work...the page keeps on refreshing but does not do anything.